# How to get the View from which context menu option was selected?

Tags: java, android, menu, contextmenu

In my app I'm dynamically creating some views and all of them have registered the same context menu.

```
for(int j = 0; j < CELLS_IN_ROW; j++) {
    MyView v = new MyView();
    ((Activity) context).registerForContextMenu(v);
}
/* ----------------------------------------------- */


    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.cell_context_menu, menu);
}

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.myOption:
            MyView viewClicked = ?????

            doSomethingDependingOnView(viewClicked);
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

But when the menu option is clicked I want to make different actions depending on which view was clicked to open the context menu. How can I do this?

Comment: MyView v = new MyView();                                               v.setID(j);  and you will get your id in Switch statement from viewClicked.getId()

Comment: @koutuk: no... see the edited code. And how to get viewClicked? It's not initialized...

Comment: final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this
             .findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
  viewGroup.addView(v); try this to add View then set CLICK listner for each view

Answer (score 3):

You have the reference on your clickedView when your onCreateContextMenu is started thanks to its argument ***view***.

onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu cM, View ***view***, ContextMenuInfo cMI)

So you have to declare some variable of View in your Activity (or Fragment),
then you should initialize that one in onCreateContextMenu and finally you can use it in onContextItemSelected

```
MyView viewClicked;

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, 
                           View view, // this is your clicked view
                           ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.cell_context_menu, menu);
viewClicked = view; // <---!!!
```

}

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.myOption:

        viewClicked.someMethod();

        doSomethingDependingOnView(viewClicked);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: Perfect Answer Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.myOption:

        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        MyView viewClicked = (MyView) info.targetView;      

        doSomethingDependingOnView(viewClicked);
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: getMenuInfo() returns null... I give up. I will do it with onLongClickListener and DialogBuilder inside the View class.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best approach but the only one that seems to work:

```
// create a global variable
Button clickedButton = null;

// save the button
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    clickedButton = (Button) v;
}

// do something with the clickedButton
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    doSomethingDependingOnView(clickedButton);
    return true;
}
```